# update cart after a chosen country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a little problem with the checkout page the order detail does not refresh

so here is my solution

1- I retrieved from the dropdown list what the user chose country

2- I sent the selection in ajax

3- in the function, I made VAT 0

but it doesn't work, the price doesn't change

this my code

js code the dropdown list what the user chose

```
 $(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function() {
        console.log("test");
        jQuery("#busineschoses").val(data_customers);
        console.log(country);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'set_zero_tax_rate',
                country: country,
                customer_biling:data_customers,
            },
           
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response.cart_total_html)
                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                if (response.success) {
                    // Update the cart total HTML
                  //  $('.order-total .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').html(response.data.cart_total_html);
                }
           
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });

});
```

in function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_set_zero_tax_rate', 'set_zero_tax_rate');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_set_zero_tax_rate', 'set_zero_tax_rate');


function set_zero_tax_rate() {
    $customer_country = $_POST['country'];




    // Check if the customer is located in the business country
    $EuCodes=['AT', 'BG', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR',

                 'GR', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IT', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MT', 'NL', 'PO', 'PT', 'RO', 'SE', 'SI', 'SK'];

                 

                        if (in_array( $customer_country, $EuCodes)  ) {
    WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);
 
                        }
                     
                          // WC()->customer->set_exempt_reason('Business customer');

                // Recalculate cart totals
                $cart = WC()->cart;
                $cart->calculate_totals();
  
                WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);

                        wp_die();
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments', 'remove_update_order_review_fragment', 10, 1 );

function remove_update_order_review_fragment( $fragments ) {
    
    // Remove the update_order_review fragment
    unset( $fragments['.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table'] );

    return $fragments;
}
```

the price does not change